# Flow type failures in Reducer?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I am pretty sure I am following the instructions correctly on how to type my actions and reducers:

### ActionTypes.js

```js
// @flow
import type Product from "../../models/Product";

type ActionNamesObject = {
  [key: string]: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } }
};

export const Actions: ActionNamesObject = {
  Product: {
    Fetch: {
      start: "PRODUCT_FETCH_START",
      success: "PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS"
    }
  }
};

export type ProductAction =
  | { type: "PRODUCT_FETCH_START" }
  | {
      type: "PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS",
      products: Product[]
    };
```

### reducer

```js
// @flow
import type Product from "../../models/Product";
import type { ProductAction } from "../actions/ActionTypes";
import { Actions } from "../actions/ActionTypes";

type ProductState = {
  +products: Product[]
};

const initialState = {
  products: []
};

export default function productsReducer(
  state: ProductState = initialState,
  action: ProductAction .   // LINE 16
): ProductState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.Product.Fetch.success:
      return { ...state, products: action.products };   // ERROR HERE
    default:
      (action: empty);   // ERROR HERE
      return state;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting flow errors where I've marked them in the reducer file.

The first error is on `products`: Cannot get action.products because property products is missing in object type. Referring to line 16. 
The second error is on `action`: Cannot cast action to empty because object type is incompatible with empty. Also referring to line 16.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductActionType` is returning two possible shapes and one doesn't have `products`

I'm not super familiar with typescript but I think you want something more like:

```
export type ProductAction = {
    type: "PRODUCT_FETCH_START" | "PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS"
    products: Product[]
}
```

I'm not sure if that second line of code that is failing is even necessary.

Comment: According to the docs I am doing it right. I want "ProductAction" to fit multiple shapes, which is what an Action type should do. Your suggestion would allow a `products` object for any type of action, which is incorrect (e.g., `PRODUCT_FETCH_START`) shouldn't have a payload of any kind.

Comment: Ah. I see. Another suggestion after reviewing this page https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-actions-action-creators 
In your action type definitions you want to typeof before your type string.

Comment: I'm not sure where the type `empty` is coming from